# Как наиболее принято разработчиками обозначать начало/конец метода комментариями в Python

Tags: python, веб-программирование, pycharm, комментарии

Хм, интересно. Сейчас задумался как лучше или как принято обозначать начало/конец метода или класса комментариями.

Я сделал вот так

```
#обработка изображений, что бы были картинки в админке, а не ссылки
def image_tag(self):
    if self.image:
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" style="width: 45px; height:45px;" />' % self.image.url)
    else:
        return 'No Image Found'

# -- обработка изображений, что бы была картинки в админке, а не ссылки
```

Или лучше так?

```
# start обработка изображений, что бы были картинки в админке, а не ссылки
def image_tag(self):
    if self.image:
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" style="width: 45px; height:45px;" />' % self.image.url)
    else:
        return 'No Image Found'

# end обработка изображений, что бы была картинки в админке, а не ссылки
```

Есть ли какой либо стандарт этого? А можно ли каким-то образом сделать что бы коммент-конец автоматически прописался в конце выделенной области?

Comment: Есть пеп https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/, докстринги не имеют явного `end`, следующий `start` является неявным `end` предыдущего метода

Comment: мне кажется, что с явным end чуть-чуть удобнее.

Comment: Ни разу не встречал, чтобы что-то подобное вообще делали. Ибо зачем

Comment: @АндрейИванов никто не запрещает вам писать как угодно в рамках синтаксиса языка. Вы спросили про стандарт — я ответил: в питоне для этого есть пеп https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @АндрейИванов функции вне класса принято разделять двумя пустыми строками (внутри класса - одной строкой) (см. все тот же pep-8). Дополнительно как-то обозначать начало/конец метода не принято. Описание того что функция делает лучше (один раз) писать в docstring в начале функции (см. https://habr.com/ru/post/499358/)

Comment: А смысл в завершающем комментарии, если сразу же после него начинающий комментарий следующего метода.Короткие аккуратные методы делать, наверно и не будет необходимости комментировать их.

Comment: три черточки - это докстринг, его нужно писать в начале блоков кода, а решетку пишут что-бы разъяснить что-то конкретное только об одной строчке? Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: да, блок в тройной кавычке будет виден в справке `help(myfunc)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Принято делать так:

```
def image_tag(self):
    '''обработка изображений, что бы были картинки в админке, а не ссылки'''

    if self.image:
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" style="width: 45px; height:45px;" />' % self.image.url)
    else:
        return 'No Image Found'

# пустая строчка
```

Конец метода не обозначается - это не нужно потому, как в глаза и так бросается лесенка влево

```
 def xxx:
     xxx:
         xxx
     xxx
     return xxx

 def yyy:
     yyy
```